# Initialize a completely empty ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to initialize an own view model in which every property is set as `null` or `""` but when I use

`ViewModel model = new ViewModel`

any property that is of type `int` gets set with `0` as it's value. I know I could go in and manually set each property to `null` or `""` but that can get lengthy, what is the proper way to initialize a completely empty view model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A property of type `int` cannot be `null` or `""`

If you want to do that you should create a `Nullable<int>` (for `null`):

```
class ViewModel
{
    public int? SomeInt{get; set;}
}
```

Setting an int to `""` makes completely no sense

Comment: Ok, well that presents me with another problem then which I will create a new post about. Thanks.

Comment: Also, setting default values is something the object's constructor should be used for (given that they are different than null, 0, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

No matter which class you are using (Model or ViewModel), only set nullable fields by `?` suffix after type like `int`. Note that `System.String` is a reference type and already nullable. `Nullable<T>` and the `?` suffix are for value types such as `Int32`, `double`, `DateTime`, etc.

```
public int? name {get; set;}//as nullable field
```

And

```
public int name {get; set;}//as not nullable field
```